# i can not Specify a variable out of the event

Tags: javascript

***i cant get a and b out of scope i need help***

*i need an find c to complete my code and idea*

**.html**

```
<div id ='hours'></div>
```

**.js**

```
var h = document.getElementById('hours');
   h.onmousedown = (e) => {var a = e.clientX; console.log('in' ,e.clientX);} 
            h.onmouseup = (e) =>{var b = e.clientX; console.log('out' , e.clientX); }
            var c = a - b ;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. show some example.

Comment: Your div is empty. How do you click on it? There will be no mouse down/up events sent to that element if you cannot click on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `a` and `b` in the starting of your code.

```
   var h = document.getElementById('hours');
   var a,b;
   h.onmousedown = (e) => {a = e.clientX; console.log('in' ,e.clientX);} 
   h.onmouseup = (e) =>{b = e.clientX; console.log('out' , e.clientX); }
   var c = a - b ;
```